# cookie not getting set

Tags: php

A very novice question. I am trying to set a cookie

```
<?php 
    $expire = time() + 24*60*60; //1 day limit
    setcookie("name","Foo", $expire);
    echo $_COOKIE["name"]; //nothing is displayed
    var_dump($_COOKIE["name"]); //returns NULL 
?>
```

I am sure it's something very trivial. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

cookie will be available in your next page load. `setcookie` just queues it to be sent along with page headers. `$_COOKIE` array contains the cookies that arrives with the request.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here but I did a page reload / refresh. But nothing shows up. Even when I try to access $_COOKIE["name"] from a different page. Shouldn't it be accessible on reload / new page?

Comment: Once you load the page, the cookie should be set, and available for all pages in the same directory. However, unless you actually need to access it from the client (eg via JS), I'd recommend looking into $_SESSIONs -- seems to be a whole lot cleaner, and you don't need to bother with the internals.